# compilation failure for spring boot application with java 9 and maven

Tags: java, maven, heroku, spring-boot, java-9

I am trying to build `spring-boot` application that uses `java-9` and would be deployed to `heroku`. As a build tool I use `maven`.

I generated `spring boot 1.5` application using `initializr`. I added `heroku` specific files and added `toolchains.xml` to `.m2` repository for `maven-compiler-plugin`.

My `pom.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.lapots.breed.platform.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-cloud-sample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>java-cloud-sample</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.9</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.9</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.release>9</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <additionalProperties>
                                <encoding.source>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding.source>
                                <encoding.reporting>${project.reporting.outputEncoding}</encoding.reporting>
                                <java.source>${maven.compiler.source}</java.source>
                                <java.target>${maven.compiler.target}</java.target>
                            </additionalProperties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <toolchains>
                        <jdk>
                            <version>1.9</version>
                            <vendor>oracle</vendor>
                        </jdk>
                    </toolchains>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>toolchain</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

When I try to compiler project using `mvn clean package` I get the error

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] javac: invalid flag: -Xmodule:null
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options

[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.031 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-30T21:08:25+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on
 project java-cloud-sample: Compilation failure
[ERROR] javac: invalid flag: -Xmodule:null
[ERROR] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
[ERROR] use --help for a list of possible options
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

`module-info` looks like this

```
module com.lapots.breed.platform.cloud.javacloudsample {
    requires spring.boot;
}
```

What is the problem? Project available here
[github repository](https://github.com/lapots/java-cloud-sample)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

maven-compiler-plugin 3.6.0 is based on the first signature of `module-info.class`, which has changed a couple of times. It is not compatible with current Java 9 signature. You should use 3.6.2 when using most recent versions of JDK 9.

Comment: wow, there can be such problem...I guess I should read about java 9 more

Comment: that's the problem when working with ea-versions. It's not official, but users want to experiment with it. So not every maven-compiler-plugin 3.6.x will work with Java 9. I will do a 3.7.0 soon to mark the first official Java 9 support release. No much difference compared to current on :)

Comment: But it seems the problem itself with `testCompile` not `raw` compile task

Comment: Oh! I get it. I changed it to version `3.6.2` but it fails with another error `Failed to parse module-info` but I did not read the message and thought it is the same error.

Comment: You'll need to use [Maven Wrapper](https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper) to get 3.6 or higher on Heroku right now.

Comment: The maven-compiler-plugin 3.7.0 is released https://www.mail-archive.com/announce@maven.apache.org/msg00804.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `toolchains.xml` does not include an entry for Java 9. Try this:

```
<toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
        <version>1.9</version>
        <vendor>oracle</vendor>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
        <jdkHome>/path/to/jdk/9</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
</toolchain>
```

Comment: but it includes. I use the same `toolchains.xml` as in `github` repository as in `.m2` folder. It seems to fail on `test` compilation

Comment: This shouldn't be the cause, it has to be compile-plugin used for the above case.

Answer (score 1):

Rightly pointed out by @Robert you need to update your `maven-compiler-plugin`. To add to it, also as stated in the [Maven/Jigsaw+9](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Java+9+-+Jigsaw) over the maven plugins. The minimum compatible version of `maven-compiler-plugin` with current [jdk-9+181](http://jdk.java.net/9/) is `3.6.2` which can be used as :

```
<!--Minimum compatible version required-->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <jdkToolchain>
            <version>9</version>
        </jdkToolchain>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

---

And to quote from one of the [examples of maven-compiler-plugin with module-info.java](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/module-info.html) here:

> For projects that want to be *compatible with older versions of Java
>   (i.e 1.8 or below)*, but also want to *provide a module-info.java for
>   Java 9 projects* must be aware that they **need to call javac twice**: the
>   module-info.java must be compiled with release=9, while the rest of
>   the sources must be compiled with a lower version of source/target.

which can be achieved using (JAVA_HOME set as 1.8.x) :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-compile</id>
        <configuration>
          <!-- compile everything to ensure module-info contains right entries -->
          <!-- required when JAVA_HOME is JDK 8 or below -->
          <jdkToolchain>
            <version>9</version>
          </jdkToolchain>
          <release>9</release>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>base-compile</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
        <!-- recompile everything for target VM except the module-info.java -->
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>module-info.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <!-- defaults for compile and testCompile -->
    <configuration>
      <!-- jdkToolchain required when JAVA_HOME is JDK 9 or above -->
      <jdkToolchain>
        <version>[1.5,9)</version>
      </jdkToolchain>
      <source>1.5</source>
      <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Few things to note there though are:

> ... you will need at least Maven 3.3.1 to specify a custom
>   jdkToolchain in your plugin configuration

---

Or you can also configure the JAVA_HOME as /jdk9/Contents/Home/bin and use the following configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-compile</id>
        <configuration>
          <!-- compile everything to ensure module-info contains right entries -->
          <release>9</release>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>base-compile</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
        <!-- recompile everything for target VM except the module-info.java -->
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>module-info.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <!-- defaults for compile and testCompile -->
    <configuration>
      <!-- Only required when JAVA_HOME isn't at least Java 9 and when haven't configured the maven-toolchains-plugin -->
      <jdkToolchain>
        <version>9</version>
      </jdkToolchain>
      <release>6</release>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```